# Migrate MySQL data, speed & efficiency

Tags: php, mysql, database, scale, migrate

I had to change the blueprint of my webapplication to decrease loading time (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5096127/best-way-to-scale-data-decrease-loading-time-make-my-webhost-happy).

This change of blueprint implies that the data of my application has to be migrated to this new blueprint (otherwise my app won't work). To migrate all my MySQL records (thousands of records), I wrote a PHP/MySQL script.

Opening this script in my browser doesn't work. I've set the time limit of the script to 0 for unlimited loading time, but after a few minutes the script stops loading. A cronjob is also not really an option: 1) strange enough it doesn't load, but the biggest problem: 2) I'm afraid this is going to cost too much resources of my shared server.

Do you know a fast and efficient way to migrate all my MySQL records, using this PHP/MySQL script?

Comment: Do you have any debugging information printed while your PHP script is running? I've always found this to be beneficial. Furthermore, to keep the system load low, try migrating records in batches using a `LIMIT` in your SQL statements; `LIMIT` also takes a secondary argument for offsetting your starting index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I solved the problem!**

Yes, it will take a lot of time, yes, it will cause an increase in server load, but it just needs to be done. I use the errorlog to check for errors while migrating.

**How?**

1) I added `ignore_user_abort(true);` and `set_time_limit(0);` to make sure the scripts keeps running on te server (stops when the while() loop is completed).

2) Within the while() loop, I added some code to be able to stop the migration script by creating a small textfile called stop.txt:

```
    if(file_exists(dirname(__FILE__)."/stop.txt")) {
    error_log('Migration Stopped By User ('.date("d-m-Y H:i:s",time()).')');
    break;
}
```

3) Migration errors and duplicates are logged into my errorlog:

```
error_log('Migration Fail => UID: '.$uid.' - '.$email.' ('.date("d-m-Y H:i:s",time()).')');
```

4) Once migration is completed (using `mail()`), I receive an email with the result of migration, so I don't have to check this manually.

This might not be the best solution, but it's a good solution to work with!

Answer (score 0):

You could try PHP's "ignore_user_abort". It's a little dangerous in that you need SOME way to end it's execution, but it's possible your *browser* is aborting after the script takes too long.

Comment: The PHP scripts prints debug informatie (success/failure/duplicate) for each user ID. I tried using ignore_user_abort(true), but I noticed some records are skipped (and still, this takes a long, long time...) However, I can't stop this script, so now I need to wait a few days before I can try another method to migrate my data. Or do you have any idea how to stop this script?

Comment: @Robin ergh~ do you have SSH access? or can you contact someone with it? you need the `kill` the process.